# Gatsby Failed Build - error "window" is not available during server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, gatsby, netlify

I have been trying to build my gatsby (react) site recently using an external package.
The link to this package is "https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-particle-animation".

As I only have the option to change the props from the components detail, I cannot read/write the package file where it all gets together in the end as it is not included in the public folder of 'gatsby-build'.

What I have tried:

- Editing the package file locally, which worked only on my machine but when I push it to netlify, which just receives the public folder and the corresponding package.json files and not the 'node-modules folder', I cannot make netlify read the file that I myself changed, as it requests it directly from the github page.

---

As a solution I found from a comment to this question, we can use the ["Patch-Package"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to save our fixes to the node module and then use it wherever we want.
This actually worked for me!

To explain how I fixed it: (As most of it is already written in the "Patch Package DOCS), so mentioning the main points:

- I first made changes to my local package files that were giving the error.(For me they were in my node_modules folder)
- Then I used the Patch Package Documentation to guide my self through the rest.
- It worked after I pushed my changes to github such that now, Patch Package always gives me my edited version of the node_module.

Comment: In my opinion, your options are: a) make a pull request to the library that fixes it, b) make a fork of the library and push it to NPM and use your fork, c) use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), or d) use a different library.

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice!
The "patch-package" trick actually worked and I am back in the flow. @cbr

Comment: Great! Be sure to add an answer that describes how you fixed it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When dealing with third-party modules that use `window` in Gatsby you need to add a `null` loader to its own webpack configuration to avoid the transpilation during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering). This is because `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser (where there is a `window`) while `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server where obviously there isn't a [`window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (because they are not even defined yet).

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-particle-animation/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `test` value is a regular expression that will match a folder under `node_modules` so, ensure that the `/react-particle-animation/` is the right name.

Using a [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) may work but keep in mind that you are adding an extra package, another bundled file that could potentially affect the performance of the site. The proposed snippet is a built-in solution that is fired when you build your application.

Comment: what if that does not work while trying to deploy on AWS?

Comment: Without seeing the code/logs it's impossible to guess what could possibly go wrong in your AWS deployment. Each case should be treated particularly. Moreover, the prompted error could be caused by some underlying issue. Please add a new answer providing details in order to allow the community to help.