# When i deployed iam getting this error: "window" is not available during server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I have a component who is using `window` to calculate the width of the screen like this:

```
const CardComponent = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
```

it working fine, all of the test also its working in my local, but when i have deployed  with actions github i am getting this error

failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.151s
error "window" is not available during server side rendering.

```
  148 |   149 | const CardComponent = () => {
> 150 |   const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
      |                                      ^
```

i found this question but i dont how can i use that

[Gatsby Failed Build - error "window" is not available during server side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308992/gatsby-failed-build-error-window-is-not-available-during-server-side-renderi)

Answer (score 1):

You can't statically generate code which relies on window, because the window property is only available in the browser and the generation happens on a backend. In other terms - it's impossible to know the value of window.innerWidth at the time which you try to access it.

Set the default value to something else - and then update it on component mount client side.

Comment: can you give a example please