# WebpackError: TypeError: document.createElement is not a function in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, document

```
const _elementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
```

'gatsby build' makes error 'WebpackError: TypeError: document.createElement is not a function'. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global objects such as `window` or `document` are available during `gatsby develop` because the interpreter/parser is the browser (where obviously there's a `window`). However, [`gatsby build` compiles your code in the Node server](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), where depending on your code logic, `document` or `window` might not be available.

You can bypass it by adding the following condition:

```
if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
  // here the logic that uses window or document
}
```

In your case:

```
if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
  const _elementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
}
```

If the responsible for using the window is a third-party dependency you can follow [Gatsby Failed Build - error "window" is not available during server side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308992/gatsby-failed-build-error-window-is-not-available-during-server-side-renderi/64313153#64313153)